# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' while using pdo wrapper class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I am using php pdo wrapper class

I am getting following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\include\SimplePDO.php:200 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\include\SimplePDO.php(200): PDO->prepare('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\include\SimplePDO.php(244): SimplePDO->query(false, Array, true) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\articles.php(57): SimplePDO->get_results(false) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\include\SimplePDO.php on line 200
```

Wrapper class code :

```
 public function query( $query, $bindings = array(), $internal_call = false )
{
    $this->counter++;
    $this->c_query = $this->pdo->prepare( $query );
    if( empty( $bindings ) )
    {
        $this->c_query->execute();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->c_query->execute( (array)$bindings );
    }

    //Alternate the response based on class internal vs. direct call to "query()"
    if( $internal_call === true )
    {
        return $this->c_query;   
    }
    elseif( $this->c_query && $this->lastid() )
    {
        return $this->lastid(); 
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
//end query()


  public function get_results( $query, $bindings = array() )
{
    return $this->query( $query, $bindings, true )->fetchAll();
}
//end get_results()
```

And query I am trying is as follows :

```
$q1 = $database1->query( "SELECT * FROM sa_articleuploads_by_admin WHERE language=? ORDER BY article_upload_date AND article_subject ASC ", array( 'marathi' ));
$objTotalRS1 = $database1->get_results( $q1 );
$counts = 1;
$len = $database1->num_rows( $q1 );

if ($len !=0){
  foreach ($objTotalRS1 as $data){
    ......////rest of my code
```

**I checked and there is language column, also I checked for typo mistakes. But couldn't find why error is thrown.**

I am trying this on XAMPP local server with php version 5.6.15)

Your kind help appreciated

Comment: A common mistake to wrap PDO in another class. Don't it leads to a maintenance nightmare and you will only be adding bugs to a perfectly working piece of software. The next PHP deveoper your company hires may know how to use PDO but he would need to learn this wrapper from scratch.